# Macro (bucle) para eliminar filas que contengan un valor en una de sus celdas

Tags: excel, vba

```
For Contador1 = 2 To 20000
    Sheets("TRÁNSITOS (LOIN_llenos)").Select
    If Sheets("TRÁNSITOS (LOIN_llenos)").Range("D" & (Contador1)) > 1080 Then
    Range("D" & (Contador1)).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End If
Next
```

Se supone que el bucle debe eliminar toda fila que tenga un valor mayor a 1080 en su celda D, pero resulta que luego de recorrer las 20000 filas aún quedan sin eliminar filas que poseen un valor mayor a 1080... ¿hay algún error o deficiencia en la macro?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay un problema de logica en tu proceso.

Lo que esta pasando es que al eliminar una fila, todas las otras filas se reenumeran...

Pero como vos seguis aumentando tu contador, empezas a saltearte filas.

Yo cambiaria tu for por un while, y no moveria el contador de filas, salvo que no hayas eliminado la fila

```
contador1 = 2
While Contador1 < 20000
    Sheets("TRÁNSITOS (LOIN_llenos)").Select
    If Sheets("TRÁNSITOS (LOIN_llenos)").Range("D" & (Contador1)) > 1080 Then
        Range("D" & (Contador1)).Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    else
        contador1 = contador1 + 1
    End If
end while
```

Answer (score 2):

La forma más eficiente de eliminar filas es borrar todas las filas a la vez, en lugar de hacerlo de una en una y esto se haría así:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim Borrar As Range
    Dim i As Long

    'Para optimizar el proceso
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TRÁNSITOS (LOIN_llenos)") 'con esto no necesitas seleccionar la hoja
        For i = 2 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count 'el bucle irá hasta la última fila del rango, sean 10 o 20000
            If .Cells(i, "D") > 1080 Then
                If Borrar Is Nothing Then
                    Set Borrar = .Cells(i, 1)
                Else
                    Set Borrar = Union(Borrar, .Cells(i, 1))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    Borrar.EntireRow.Delete 'aquí borramos todas las filas de una vez, que es más eficiente y rápido

    'Devolvemos las opciones por defecto
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Me tóme la libertad de mejorar un poquito tu codigo y si, efectivamente @gbianchi♦ tiene toda la razón
te sugiero lo siguiente:

```
Dim Rango_usado As Range, _
    Contador1 As Integer
Sheets("TRÁNSITOS (LOIN_llenos)").Select
Set Rango_usado = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
For Contador1 = 2 To Rango_usado.Rows.Count
    If Cells(Contador1, 4).Value > 1080 Then
        Cells(Contador1, 4).EntireRow.Delete
        Contador1 = Contador1 - 1
    End If
Next Contador1
```

1. Declaro las variables a utilizar
2. Selecciono la hoja, como veras lo mejor es colocarla fuera del `For`
3. Con `UsedRange` obtengo el rango en uso
   [Worksheet.UsedRange property (Excel)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.usedrange?f1)
   pero si el número de filas en cuestión es fijo puedes seguir usando los 20000 en tu `For`
4. Veo que el cotador lo inicias en 2 por el encabezado me imagino, obtnego el nro de fila en uso
5. Ya no es necesario volver a referirse al la hoja y rango en cuestión por ello uso directamente `Cells`
6. Entonces sin selecionar (ya que a mi parecer se ve feo eso avance celda por celda) y si culpe el criterio precedo a eliminar la fila
7. y resto 1 al contador

Answer (score 0):

La mejor manera de borrar filas en un bucle es hacerlo al reves en el for, me explico en vez de hacer un for de 1 al total de filas, hay que hacerlo del total de filas a 1 con step -1 y ya está.
for i = max to 1 step -1

next i

Comment: Saludos, puedes mejorar tu respuesta agregando código de ejemplo funcional, por el momento solo parece un comentario. ;)